# Set width <li> element to longest text

Tags: css

I'm showing three USP's with icons and text in the header of a website. I've made an unordered list, each list item with a `before` element that contains a FontAwesome icon. Now in the list items, I have a line break after specific words and I want the width of the list item to be as wide as the longest line. Is this making sense?
Preferably I'm looking for an all CSS solution. Can anyone help?

My HTML:

```
<ul id='usp-icons-header'>  
<li class='fa fa-truck'>Voor 18:00 besteld =<br><strong>morgen in huis</strong></li>
<li class='fa fa-eur'>Vanaf €49,- =<br><strong>gratis verzending</strong></li> 
<li class='fa fa-credit-card'><strong>Veilig</strong><br>betalen</li>
</ul>
```

My CSS:

```css
#usp-icons-header li {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
}

#usp-icons-header li:before {
  color: #b79f64;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: That seems already to be the case. Each list item snugly fits around its contents. You may add `white-space: nowrap` to prevent lines wrapping after all. They will still break on the `<br>` elements you explicitly inserted.

Comment: an li element will already go to the longs line since this is default behavior unless the size is to small for the longest line to appear?

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is..could you made a demo and explain **in greater detail** what isn't working for you?

Comment: This is actually some custom stuff in a Wordpress website and indeed it seems it SHOULD be working, but isn't because of something else. I didn't actually test this code outside of the website, which was probably a good idea.
The problem in more detail is that the list always takes the width of the text before the break tag. But if the text after the break tag is longer, that line should determine the width.
You've got me as far as that I should be looking for the problem in a different place. So thanks a lot!